# Django documentation Part 2: why can't I import Poll, PollAdmin and Choices in a single line?

Tags: django

Working on the Django tutorial "Writing your own Django app," and I'm on [Part 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial02/).

Midway through, it instructs me to add a line to the admin so that the admin will recognize not just Poll (and PollAdmin, which the tutorial has been configuring for some custom poll-presenting options), but also Choice. Here's the (short) updated admin.py:

```
from polls.models import Poll
from polls.models import Choice
from django.contrib import admin

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,                  {'fields': ['question']}),
        ('Date information',    {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
        ]

admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
admin.site.register(Choice)
```

Looking at this, I can't figure out why I can't simply write

```
admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin, Choice)
```

except that this gives me a TypeError, because

```
register() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)
```

This seems really... arbitrary to me. I don't understand why register only takes at most 3 arguments. My understanding of Django is still at a very voodoo, cargo-cult level, so I get that this Just. Doesn't. Work., but I was wondering if some light could be shed on why I can't pull all three elements from admin.site at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you've got two separate types of registration going on here, with two separate types of objects. I think you're thinking that this is saying "register these three things with the admin", but that's not quite what's going on.

The first line is saying "register the Poll model with the admin, using the PollAdmin class I've defined."

The second line is saying "register the Choice model with the admin, using the default settings."

So it wouldn't make sense to have them all in the same line. You're only registering one model at a time, but one uses some explicit options, and the other uses the default options.

Comment: You understand what I wasn't understanding -- I did indeed think it was a matter of registering everything with the admin, not registering Poll using the PollAdmin class. Thanks for the brief and cogent explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`register` accepts only one or two arguments (the third is `self` which passed automatically by the class). If you specify one argument, it must be a model class, and the Django admin will simply use the default `ModelAdmin` for it. If you specify two arguments, the first must be a model class, and the second must be a `ModelAdmin` subclass.

You can't just arbitrarily keep passing arguments to methods, each argument *means something*.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from django.contrib import admin.site

register(Poll, PollAdmin, Choice)
```

Suppose, you have a method within a class "myclass" , such as :

```
def example_method(param1,param2):
//do stuff
```

When you use `myclass.example_method(param2)`, you have `param1` being implicitly passed to `myclass`.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the source code. Is not a Django stuff, but is basic Python.

The register method:

```
def register(self, model_or_iterable, admin_class=None, **options):
    """
    stuff to read
    """
    #...code...
    validate(admin_class, model)
    self._registry[model] = admin_class(model, self)
```

initiates a ModelAdmin object ...

```
class ModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):
    def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
        self.model = model
        self.opts = model._meta
        self.admin_site = admin_site
        super(ModelAdmin, self).__init__()
```

... if you read the use of "option", is there to solve a bug and if someone will ever want to extend ModelAdmin! Like so:

```
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def __init__(self, model, admin_site, my_param = None):
        self.my_property = my_param
        super(MyModelAdmin, self).__init__(model, admin_site)
```

If you just started learning Django and Python this kind of questions are totally useless and non-productive!